# How can I read pre-fetched server side data with a typescript client?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, window, global

I'm using the below function to return initial server-rendered markup and data in case of lack of javascript support:

```
    export const serverRender = async () => {
        const { port, host } = config;
        const resp = await 
    axios.get(`http://${host}:${port}/testData.json`);

        const initialData = resp.data;
        return {
            initialMarkup: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App initialData={initialData} />),
            initialData,
        };
    };
```

I serve this data to my template as follows (details aren't that important):

```
    app.setViewEngine("pug");
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../assets")));
    app.enableCors();
    await app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Nest App listening on port ${PORT}`);
    });
```

In my template, I use `pug` interpolation to read `initialData` into the `window` object in javascript (`window.initialData = #{initialData}`). If my client was a javascript client I could read from the `window` object like this: `window.initialData`, but Typescript doesn't allow this.

My question is, what is the best way to pass pre-fetched data and pass it to the client side? Ie. so I can do something like this when I render the client:

```
    /* somehow grab pre-fetched data */
    ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById("root")); // entry point for webpack
```

I'm not saying this is the best way (which is another reason why I'm asking this question), but in the past for small pure javascript projects I've assigned the data to `window` as above and then in the client rendering of my `react`, I've done something like this:

```
    const initialData = window.initialData;
    ReactDOM.hydrate(<App initialData={initialData} />, document.getElementById("root")); // entry point for webpack
```

This doesn't fly in Typescript

N/a

Error message for the `window` case: 
`Property 'initialData' does not exist on type 'Window'`

But I want to find some other way anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare how the window global object looks like with your custom initialData value:

```
declare global {
    interface Window { 
        initialData: any; 
    }
}
```

Once you've declared this, then:

```
const initialData = window.initialData;
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Out of curiosity, is there a better way that you know of?

Comment: @StarLlama When I have had to do this (i.e. get data to my client side app from the server), I've stored the data in a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and then retrieved it on the client using e.g. document.getElementById("yourDivId").dataset.initialData.